# Handlig multiple window.prompts at the same time using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I need to rename an existing group. While creating group there was only single window prompt I used below code to handle

```
casper.setFilter("page.prompt", function (msg, currentValue) {
    if (msg === "Enter new group name") {
        return ID;
    }
});
```

Now I want to rename the created group with new name
and it throws window prompt like below
[image: 1st window prompt]

and after clicking on OK it throws another prompt window like below
[image: second prompt window]

How do I handle this situation?

and this is my code after @artjom B suggestion

```
casper.setFilter("page.prompt", function (msg, currentValue) {
    if (msg === "Enter new group name") {
        return t;
    }
});

casper.setFilter("page.confirm", function (msg) {
    return msg.indexOf("Are you sure you want to rename group "+ID1+" to "+t+"?") !== -1;
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.click("span.label:nth-child(4)");
    console.log("Clicking on Rename button");
});
```

Comment: it seem to be ...there is one more prompts triggering from another place before replacing the group.u can put if condition there to avoid two times .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you. I just removed validation part from second filter.

```
casper.then(function () {
this.setFilter("page.prompt", function (msg, currentValue) {
    if (msg === "Rename group "+ID1) {          
        this.wait(5000)   
        this.echo("I'm Here")                                                                            
        return t;
    }
})
this.setFilter("page.confirm", function (msg) {                                        
    return true                           
})
this.click("span.label:nth-child(4)");
console.log("renamed the newly created group");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the second window is a confirmation dialog (`confirm()`), so you can additionally register the ["page.confirm" filter](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-confirm):

```
casper.setFilter("page.prompt", function (msg, currentValue) {
    if (msg === "Enter new group name") {
        return ID;
    }
});

casper.setFilter("page.confirm", function (msg) {
    return msg.indexOf("Are you sure you want to rename group \"" + groupName + " to \"" + newGroupName + "\"?") !== -1;
});
```

The return value of the callback determines whether you confirm or not. If you don't care what the message is, then you can `return true`.

Additionally, it may be necessary to wait a little after you click the button which triggers the `prompt()` which then triggers the `confirm()`. Those event handlers are asynchronous and they run outside of the CasperJS control flow. So you need to let CasperJS wait a little after the click in order to let those handlers execute. `casper.thenClick(selector).wait(100)` should be enough.

Comment: I have made some changes to the question by modifying code

Comment: You forgot some quotes inside of the string. You probably shouldn't try to match the whole thing.

Comment: Nope..still it is not working. And could you tell me when to click on Rename button after casper.setFilters  ?

Comment: It looks fine the way you do it. Add `console.log()` to the filter callbacks see whether the those are even called.

Comment: yes i tried with console.log() but it is not calling the function

Comment: Which one or does nothing appear? Then this is some other problem with the page. Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.